# Removing Functionality from a Git Branch, and later merging it back in?

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, branching-and-merging

Say I have two branches:

1. Development
2. Production

I have a file on both branches right now, but I want to remove some `<li>` elements from the production branch, but keep it in my Development branch.

So I go in and make a commit to my production branch removing that element.

Later on I decide I want to add those `<li>` elements back into the production branch (specifically from the `<li>` elements in my updated Development branch).

If I simply do a merge, the elements will not be added back in. What would be the best way to update the Production branch in this case?

Comment: `git revert <the_commit_where_you_took_them_out>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to have a **universal** approach for deleting the data in one branch and then merging that data back via a different branch, while at the same time keeping other changes isolated in their respective branches (more on that later). But there might be an approach **specific** to your workflow.

## Explicit Solution

If you do not have other changes in your `master` branch, then you're looking for this:

```
git checkout master
vim <file where you delete lis>
git add <file>
git commit

git checkout development
git merge master
git revert master
```

Let me explain what happens there:

1. You do your changes in `master` branch - there you delete all those `<li>` and commit the update.
2. After that you switch to the development branch and merge your `master` branch there. So that both branches are on the same page. Thus all subsequent changes in the development branch will be the changes visible to Git as "difference comparing to master" - and they will be applied in future merges of development branch to master.
3. Then `git revert master` creates a new commit in development branch with the inversion of the changes made last in the `master` branch - i.e. it effectively adds `<li>` back, because their removal was the last commit in `master`.

Later, when you merge `development` to `master` it will restore your `<li>` there.

One particular thing to stress again: it works well only if `master` branch doesn't have any other changes except for `li` removal. That's because when you execute `git merge master` it brings all `master` changes to the development branch, which might be undesired.

Note that you can't avoid merging `master` to the development branch, because they need to have a common ancestor commit where `<li>` were deleted. Also the development branch needs to have an explicit commit, where `<li>` were added back. Only with this setup Git will apply that commit later, when you will be merging development branch to `master`.

## Implicit Solution

The universal suggested approach in this case is to remember the commit id, where you deleted `li`s. Later you will need to revert it manually after merging development branch to master:

```
git checkout master
git merge development

git revert <id of the commit where you deleted li>
```

There might be other solutions, but they are more organizational ones or require other tools beyond just simple Git.